# Populate a dropdown with options selected from another "multi select" drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to populate a drop down menu based on the values entered into a text box from another multi-select drop down? Basically, I want all the values that are selected in the multi select drop down to appear as options in another drop down. Any ideas?? Please help me!!

Comment: That another dropdown has additional options compared to the first one?

Comment: Is this part of a flow where the user can't go back and change values, or does it need to take into consideration what happens when the multi-select removes the selected value in the drop down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
multiSelectInput.on('change', function(event){
  var options = [];
  var multiValue = multiSelectInput.value.split(',');
  multiValue.forEach(function(value){
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.innerHTML = value;
    options.push(option);
  });
  selectElement.innerHTML = options.join('');
})
```

Something like this might work? You might have to tweak it based on how you will parse the value of the multi-select input. This is all theoretical, of course, since I have no idea what your code looks like or what kind of multi-select you're using. Good luck :)

Comment: <html>
<head>
 <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<select name="meal" id="meal" onChange="changecat(this.value);" multiple>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<select name="category" id="category">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
</select>
</body>

Comment: This is my code:

Comment: Basically, if I select A in multi select drop down, A should appear in the other drop down. If I select A,C then A and C should appear as options in the multi select drop down.

Comment: Your implementation of multiple attribute on select will not trigger an onChange event; it's meant for use with a form POST submission, where the value of the select would be assessed at the time of submission. In other words, I don't believe you'll be able to dynamically determine when something has been selected or not. You should reassess why you're using a multiple select instead of something like a set of checkboxes. If you're able, I'd recommend something like this: https://jsbin.com/racoxuraca/8/

Comment: OMG!!! Thank you so much!!!! This was exactly what I was looking for!!! Basically my multi select drop down has checkboxes using which multiple options can be selected. Will try it with that and get back to you!! thanks a ton!!

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#deals').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            buttonWidth: 250,
            maxHeight: 250,
            enableFiltering: true
        });
        });
</script>
<p align="center">
<B>      Select the option(s)<br><br><br>
<select id="options" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option></select>

Comment: I have implemented the above code using bootstrap and bootstrap multi select. So my Select options will have a search box and checkboxes with many options to select from. Can you please try with the above code??? This is how my company people want it to function. So, instead of checkboxes, can you try with <option>??

Comment: I am insisting on multi select because there are over 600 options to be included, with an option of selecting all of em.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a good reference for Bootstrap, but it should be fairly simple to convert the `.on('change')` to an `.on('click')` for the options, and then use some sort of state variable to keep track of whether the option has been clicked before. Best of luck

Comment: No problem. But tysm for your help! :D But w/o bootstrap do you know how to do the same thing for multi select drop down? Because there are over 600 options and I can't have 600 check boxes. That's why.

Comment: This should help: https://jsbin.com/nacamosixo/1